# Why would a Google Test pass in one machine yet fail in another?

Tags: c++, c, initialization, googletest

We use GoogleTest to test our code in Eclipse but I have a test which passes in one machine and fails in another due to a pointer de-reference and I'm not sure why it runs differently. This test was recently added by a jr dev to the end of the test file to validate a small change. The test included an error yet passed somehow in their machine:

```
TEST(TEST_SUITE, TEST_NAME)
{
    uint8* response_data;
    uint16 response_length = 1;
    response_data[0] = 0x54;
    //more code and actual validation
}
```

The attempt to write to a null pointer caused my application to fail, yet somehow in their machine the data was defined and therefore able to pass. I set breakpoints at the first line of the test to see and this is what I get:

My Machine - null pointer:
[image: Failing Test at first line in test]

Their Machine - defined pointer (and length):
[image: Passing Test at first line in test]

Somehow, although the call stack is the same and although the tests run in the same order, in one machine the variables are somehow carrying some other values.

Is there a reason why this would behave differently on two different machines with the same codebase? Do variables defined in a test not have a limited scope?

Comment: `uint8* response_data;` - You don't initialize the pointer here (this is **NOT** a null pointer, it is uninitialized), so `response_data[0] = 0x54;` leads to *undefined behavior*

Comment: ... and the reason why it behaves differently is because that's the meaning. It's *undefined*. So just don't do it, problem solved.

Comment: @UnholySheep I understand that the pointer wasn't initialized. I guess I would've expected it to be null and crash in the jr. dev's environment like it did in mine, yet somehow it passed.

Comment: Didn't your compiler warn about this?

Comment: Even if it was null that doesn't mean the application would crash - it's still *undefined behavior* which means the compiler is free to do anything

Comment: @avivas This isn't Java or C# etc. . There is no runtime check "crash if null". Upside is speed, downside this thing here: Predicting specific outcomes won't work.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to prevent bad tests from being written and checked in, but obviously a passing GoogleTest project is not enough. Is there a way to prevent something like this from happening again?

Comment: Code reviews and linters/code analyzing tools come to mind. Also increasing warning levels on the compilation settings to maximum (and treat warnings as errors).

Comment: ***Is there a way to prevent something like this from happening again?*** Figure out why your compiler did not warn about this (or the warning was ignored) and correct the situation.

Comment: "*Is there a way to prevent something like this from happening again?*" Yes, tests your programs using a memory checker, like for example [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org). (Note: As this is about `auto` variables, as opposed to dynamically allocated memory, use Valgrind's experimental (!) option `--tool=exp-sgcheck`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As UnholySheep mentioned in the comments, `responseData` was uninitialized, and your workmates are using it.

As the Wikipedia points out, the C++ standard does not specify what should happen in this case (this is called [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). That means it could work with them and not with you. Thus, if you are using a different compiler than they are (or even if you set different compilation flags like optimisation levels, or whether you use debug), you may not get the same results.

To explain your specific case more deeply, with them, it seems the pointer is not set to anything (`responseData` had a garbage value), whereas with you, `responseData` was set to nullptr.

Comment: Note: It doesn't even have to be a different compiler - even changing compilation settings (e.g.: optimization level) can already lead to different results

Comment: In this case the behaviour depends on what is in tge preexisting stack memory. This could well vary between one program instance and another.

Comment: @doron Yes, I was going to explain this, but I then felt I didn't need to overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 3):

Writing to an uninitialized pointer is undefined behaviour. This means that what happens is totally up for grabs. It might segfault or worse, overwrite some memory.

What it does depends on the state of the machine at the time. This is why you get different behaviour on different machines.

Comment: "*... or worse*" do nothing. :-(